# How do I parameterize my Class parameter in this case?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have the following Utility class and method:

```
public class KSoapUtility {

public static KSoapObjectParseable parseObject (SoapObject soapObject, Class clazz) {
    KSoapObjectParseable obj = null;
    try {
        obj = (KSoapObjectParseable)clazz.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (obj != null) {
        String[] propertyNames = obj.getPropertyNames();
        for (String propertyName: propertyNames) {
            obj.setProperty(propertyName, soapObject.getPropertyAsString(propertyName));
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

}

I then call this method as follows:

```
Instruction instruction = (Instruction)KSoapUtility.parseObject(instructionSoapObject, Instruction.class);
```

Note that my "Instruction" class implements an interface called "KSoapObjectParseable".

It works fine, but in my Utility class Eclipse warns:

> Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized

Correctly so, however, if I parameterize the method argument as follows:

```
Class<KSoapObjectParseable> clazz
```

Then the following call wont compile:

```
Instruction instruction = (Instruction)KSoapUtility.parseObject(instructionSoapObject, Instruction.class);
```

giving the error:

```
The method parseObject(SoapObject, Class<KSoapObjectParseable>) in the type KSoapUtility is not applicable for the arguments (SoapObject, Class<Instruction>)
```

So my question is, how do you parameterize my method argument and still be able to call it by passing in "MyClass,class" that implements KSoapObjectParseable ?

Comment: What's the purpose of that parameter? Are you trying to allow the client to specify any subclass of `KSoapObjectParseable`?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of that parameter is to allow the client to specifiy any subclass of KSoapObjectParseable.

Comment: The suggestion provided by @Jens doesn't make any sense; it's an example of how to *use* this method, not how to make it clean and generic, and apparently (unsurprisingly) `KSoapObjectParseable` is either an interface or an abstract class.

Comment: Correct, KSoapObjectParseable is an interface as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you expect the caller to be passing in a class that is or extends `KSoapObjectParseable`, so try this (with the necessary try/catch logic):

```
public static <T extends KSoapObjectParseable> T parseObject(SoapObject soapObject, Class<T> clazz) {
    T obj = clazz.newInstance();
    // stuff
    return obj;
}
```

Note also that since you're passing in that `SoapObject`, it would be better to make this an instance method there if you control that class.

Finally, don't ever just swallow exceptions like you're doing here, and don't catch `Exception`; in fact, most of the time, printing the stack trace isn't even helpful (because the caller will want to log it using the appropriate logging system for the application). Instead, wrap that `InstantiationException` into an `IllegalArgumentException` (because they passed in an uninstantiable class) and rethrow.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!  I haven't used generics extensively and I knew it could be done, just wasn't sure how in this case. Your example works perfectly for me, and its so simple now that I see it. Much appreciate your time.

Comment: I have also updated my exception handling as per your suggestions. Oh and I don't control the SoapObject class, its coming from the ksoap library.